# How to tell Transmission app to not show its window every time the system is restarted?

Tags: macos, transmission

I have set autolaunch for Transmission app.

Every time, the system is restarted, Transmission shows it's window.

Is it possible, to keep it hidden after restart ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to System Preferences from the Apple Menu in the top left part of your screen.

Click on the Account tab (under the System section), click on your account, then Login Items.

This should show you a list of applications under something that says `These items will open automatically when you log in:`

In the list of applications, there is a hide column on the left with checkboxes next to every application. If you check one of the boxes, the application will be hidden after it starts up every time you log in.

That should do it.